# htaccess 301 redirect to insert a character

Tags: .htaccess

I need any url ending in numeric characters after the last slash to insert a character (_) before the numbers. I've reached this point which incorrectly only grabs the last group of (non-slash characters/) preceding the last slash then inserts the underscore and numbers. 
    Not working:

```
 ^([^/]+/)+([0-9]+)$ $1_$2 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

So I need mysite.com/long/url/34566 to become mysite.com/long/url/_34566
The above code makes mysite.com/url/_34566

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9]+)$ /$1/_$2 [NE,L,R=301]
```

In your regex problem is with `([^/]+/)+` as only last captured group before `/` is captured in `$1`, hence you get `url` in $1 for `/long/url/34566`.

In my rule `.+` will match anything before last `/` hence it will capture `/long/url`.

Comment: Mine seems to be matching the last group - as does yours. FYI This is a wordpress site but I'm running the rule first.

Comment: Problem is with `([^/]+/)+` as only last part is captured in `$1` hence you get `url` in `$1`. Here `.+`  will match anything before last `/`. You need to keep this rule as your very first rule and completely clear browser cache.

Comment: Thanks. I did clear my cache but the new url is dropping a piece of the old url. So mysite.com/really/long/url/1234 is becoming mysite.com/long/url/_1234. Maybe there is something else going on since your code looks like it should work :(

Comment: Possibly you don't have this rule in root .htaccess. If you have `RewriteBase` defined above this rule then you can use: `RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9]+)$ $1/_$2 [NE,L,R=301]`

Comment: Just saw and made that change and it works! Thanks!!